# nginx proxy_pass / location

Tags: nginx, proxypass

```
location / {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 root $root_path;                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 try_files $uri $uri/ @gosite;                                                                                                                                                                                      
 expires max;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 access_log off;                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

location @gosite { 
  proxy_pass http://localhost:9110; 
}
```

When i came on http://site/  i got 403, how can i do proxy_pass when user come on / page (on backend, page handler works on "/")?

if uri like /detail, all is ok, static content on nginx side and page from backend

Answer (score 0):

The error 403 comes when you are trying to access a forbidden file.

I am not able to understand your problem exactly, but if you are worried with 403 error, you must checkout for some permissions, possibly to the index file(as you defined in nginx) in the project folder of localhost:9110.

I would suggest you to switch on your access log for you server block, and check them out(do tail -f) to find which file is being accessed when you visit http://site/ and provide proper permission(using chmod) to that file.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options...

Stop testing for the presence of a static directory by removing the `$uri/` clause from the `try_files` statement:

```
location / {
    ...
    try_files $uri @gosite;
    ...
}
location @gosite {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9110;
}
```

Alternatively, add a specific location for the URI `/`:

```
location / {
    ...
    try_files $uri $uri/ @gosite;
    ...
}
location @gosite {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9110;
}
location = / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9110;
}
```

Incidently, the `$uri/` clause is useful in conjunction with the [`index` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index). If you are not using static `index.html` files (or similar), you probably do not need the `$uri/` clause.

The 403 error is caused by the fact that there is not a static file called `index.html` in the document root.